# CoreUI console message

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, osx-lion

After switching to Lion I started having strange message in the debug console:

```
CoreUI: Unable to lookup effect preset with Style 4 for {Normal, Active, On/Blue}
```

It happens when the main window becomes ordered front or back, for example when I switch between applications with Command+Tab. I googled it, but it seems nobody experienced it.

I have localised the area. On my main view I have several CALayers where I draw the content. Also there are two subviews. The subviews are NSViews with normal NSButtons. If I do not add the subviews the message does not appear any more.
It worked fine in Snow Leopard, though.

Has any one had a similar message? Any ideas?

**Update:** 
The problem has been localised. On one of my subviews I use buttons with a custom cell. In the cell I override the following method:

```
- (NSBackgroundStyle)interiorBackgroundStyle
{
    return [self state] == NSOnState ? NSBackgroundStyleLowered : [super interiorBackgroundStyle];
}
```

The cell looks and works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a log message from a framework outside of your code base without indication that you are doing anything wrong.

It may or may not be a bug. Whenever in doubt, write up a bug/radar and send it in. Be sure to include as much information that you can:

- Steps to reproduce the issue
- Any sample code or a project that you are comfortable sharing that reproduces the issue.
- The version of Xcode you are using
- The version of the OS you are running
- etc.

Comment: No, it does not cause any problems so far, just floods the console with the messages making testers nervous. Thanks for your advice, I will write to radar.

Comment: Post the radar number if you have a chance.

Comment: I have opened a case in the Radar. Problem ID: 10107282